# How to fix css, js not load, view engine ejs?

Tags: javascript, css, express, load, ejs

2 ejs page of my project use the same script,css file. But one works and the other not load css, js.

problem is when I start express server and

> load path /addshift      first, /addshift/edit works.
>
> load path /addshift/edit first, /addshift/edit not load css, js

path:

> index.ejs : root/addshift/views/index.ejs
>
> edit.ejs  : root/addshift/views/edit.ejs
>
> script.js : root/addshift/script.js
>
> style.css : root/addshift/css/style.css

Comment: sounds like issue with relative path in your html

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar any recommendation for me ?

Comment: can't know for sure without seeing your code and your folder layout.